# Foundation off canvas won't work?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

Alright, I followed all the instructions on the page, or so I thought, but I still can't get the Off Canvas to  work in my Foundation?

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

That's how I'm instructed to put it in, as per the website. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html
Or so I thought? Also

```
        <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <nav class="tab-bar">
      <section class="left-small">
        <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
      </section>

      <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
        <h1 class="title">Foundation</h1>
      </section>

      <section class="right-small">
        <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
      </section>
    </nav>

    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
      <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>

    <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
      <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label>Users</label></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hari Seldon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>

    <section class="main-section">
      <!-- content goes here -->
    </section>

  <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

That's all done as per instructed? 
What I end up with is the menu showing, but when I click on the button for the off canvas to pop, it doesn't pop?

EDIT
Alright, so I tried what you suggested, and it did pop. BUUUT rather than pop out from the side, it popped, shoving everything DOWN, and made this tiny scroll bar?

Alright, this was what it looked like, upon entering your code. THen...
[image: One of my issues]

When I clicked it, this happened...

[image: Other issue]

See all that white space? The heading Welcome to Foundation is one mouse scroll down. See the little bitty scroll bar next to the popped menu? =/

Comment: There's not a single canvas reference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got it.
Move $(document).foundation(); to onload in the body tag. Or at least put it last inside body tags. You can leave the .js references inside head tags. I did this way:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
</head>
<body onload="$(document).foundation();">
    <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <nav class="tab-bar">
                <section class="left-small">
                    <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </section>

                <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
                    <h1 class="title">Foundation</h1>
                </section>

                <section class="right-small">
                    <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </section>
            </nav>

            <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
                <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                    <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
                <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                    <li><label>Users</label></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hari Seldon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <section class="main-section">
                <!-- content goes here -->
            </section>

            <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope it works!

PD: It's really frustrating that i had 2 comments trying to correct my mistake, and zero answers trying to solve the question.

Comment: I REALLY appreciate your aide in solving this. I tried what you recommended and I included pictures as to what happened when I did =/

Comment: it works and don't forget to change $ to jQuery first if not works : `jQuery(document).foundation();`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest copy and pasting all the following code into a brand new html page and checking it. Then you can either just build off it or figure out what the problem is on your old code.

Make **sure** that all the linked files (css and js) are getting loaded. You might need to change the paths on the example. It is absolutely essential to make sure they are getting accessed. Use your web browser inspector to see if your getting any 404 (not found) errors.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>



    <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
      <div class="inner-wrap">
        <nav class="tab-bar">
          <section class="left-small">
            <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
          </section>

          <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
            <h1 class="title">Foundation</h1>
          </section>

          <section class="right-small">
            <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
          </section>
        </nav>

        <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
          <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </aside>

        <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
          <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li><label>Users</label></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hari Seldon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </aside>    

        <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>



        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <h1>Welcome to Foundation</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="panel">
              <h3>We&rsquo;re stoked you want to try Foundation! </h3>
              <p>To get going, this file (index.html) includes some basic styles you can modify, play around with, or totally destroy to get going.</p>
              <p>Once you've exhausted the fun in this document, you should check out:</p>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
              <p><a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs">Foundation Documentation</a><br />Everything you need to know about using the framework.</p>
            </div>
                <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
                  <p><a href="http://github.com/zurb/foundation">Foundation on Github</a><br />Latest code, issue reports, feature requests and more.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
                  <p><a href="http://twitter.com/foundationzurb">@foundationzurb</a><br />Ping us on Twitter if you have questions. If you build something with this we'd love to see it (and send you a totally boss sticker).</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>    

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this CSS code:

```
.inner-wrap {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```